# $D=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^n: x_1^2 + x_2^2 <1\}$, $u$ harmonic in $D$, $u=2x_1^2$ in $\partial D$, find $u(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Let $D=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^n: x_1^2 + x_2^2 <1\}$. Suppose that
>   exists $u$ harmonic in $D$, continuous in $\overline{D}$ and that
>   coincides with $2x_1^2$ in $\partial D$. Find $u(0)$.

By the Representation Theorem for $u$ harmonic:

$$u(x) = -\int_{\partial \Omega} g(y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}(x,y) dS(y)$$
For our problem, $g(x_1,x_2) = 2x_1^2$ and $G$ would be the Green Function for the ball in $2$ dimensions: $$G(x_1,x_2) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}(\ln(|x_2-x_1|)-\ln(|x_1||x_2-x_1^*|))$$ where $x_1^* = \frac{x_1}{|x_1|^2}$

In $B(0,1)$, the normal $v$ is simply $(x_1,x_2)$, and we know $\frac{\partial G}{\partial v} = \nabla G\cdot v$.

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1} = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{|x_2-x_1|}\frac{x_2-x_1}{|x_2-x_1|}-\frac{1}{|x_1||x_2-x_1^*|}\frac{\cdots}{\cdots}\right)$$

I didn't finish the derivative calculation because I think it's too big s this is not the way to solve this exercise. I'd have to multiply this entire thing by $2x_1^2$ and integrate for $x=(0,0)$. Doesn't this expression has a singulatiry on $(0,0)$ by the way?

Or should I simply see that $g(0,0) = 2(0)^2$ and thus the entire integrand is $0$ and thus $u(0) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a harmonic function, the value at a point is equal to the average around a circle centred at that point.  In this case you want to take the average of $2 \cos^2(\theta)$ for $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, i.e.
$$ \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} 2 \cos^2(\theta) \; d\theta $$

Comment: So it is $\int_{B_1(0)}2x_1^2\ dx$. I could solve it by doing double integration, but you transformed to a polar equation. How exactly?

Comment: If I do $x_1=\cos \theta$ and $x_2 = \sin \theta$ then I need to substitute $dx=r d\theta dr$ but there's no $r$

Comment: I think I can also see $2x_1^2$ as $(2x_1,0)\cdot (x_1,x_2)$ where $(x_1,x_2)$ is a normal vector. Then I can use the divergence theorem, I guess

Comment: You can use the average around a circle instead of the average over a disk.

Comment: Wait, for the property of the average value to be applied, doesn't the function need to have the closure contained in an open $\Omega$ and $f$ harmonic in $\Omega$? I know that the closure of $D$ is contained in $\Omega$, but $u$ is harmonic only in $D$, not on $\Omega$

Comment: Since the function is continuous on $\overline{D}$, the integral around the unit circle is the limit as $r \to 1-$ of the integrals around circles of radius $r$, which are inside the region.

Comment: But how should I find the expression for $u$ in the border of this circle of radius $1-\epsilon$?

Comment: You don't.  The point is that the average around each circle of radius $r < 1$ is the value at the centre, so the average around the unit circle, which is the limit of that as $r \to 1-$, is also the value at the centre.